# Some key bindings in `screen` do not work as expected

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, raspbian

I recently installed `screen` for Raspbian Buster using bash and it doesn't seem to work completely.

I am able to create a new window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> and flip between the windows. I can see the windows using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd>.

However the split screen commands do not do anything. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>|</kbd> does not split the screen vertically. I get no response doing this. Also, typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd> does not bring up the help menu.

Is this normal? Has anyone else run into this? How to fix this?

Some details:

- It's my Raspberry Pi and I just log in and use the GUI terminal. The terminal is LXTerminal 0.3.2.
- Without starting `screen`, typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> gets `^A`. If I run `cat` and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> I get `^A`.
- Sole <kbd>?</kbd> and <kbd>|</kbd> work fine as expected (I need <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get them).

Comment: Please see `man 1 screen`, the "CUSTOMIZATION" part. It mentions files like `$HOME/.screenrc` that may hold a custom config. Review them, maybe they modify keybindings in your case.

Comment: If there are problems with `screen`, consider using `tmux`. It's newer and somewhat different in details. I personally prefer `tmux` and I can think of two reasons to use `screen`: (1) if you have already got used to it; (2) `screen` is probably more available on various systems (including legacy ones). // Trying (and liking) `tmux` may render the question no longer significant to you.

Comment: I figured it out. You can't have ctrl-a held down when you type | or ?. I'm dumb